My BigQuery scheduled query is not updating the aggregate table when it's originally scheduled, but works when scheduled during my online hours
Goal: Run a query and aggregate that data to a preexisting table every day at 6:30 AM EST which is connected to a Looker Studio report
Problem: When I schedule and test the query during my working hours and let it run, it works (around 9:30-10:30am EST). The table is updated as expected and I can see the data with my connected Looker Studio report. However, when I let the scheduled query run the next day at my desired time, 6:30AM, it runs successfully according to the logs however the table in both BigQuery and Looker Studio will not be updated.
Other information: My other scheduled queries are working as expected, but they are running DELETE from table commands. My original query to aggregate the data works as expected when I run it manually in the console, or do a Scheduled Backfill. I am using the Destination for Query results form to identify my dataset and table location. My current roles are BigQuery Data Viewer and Owner.
Why is this not working when I need it to run? Why am I not getting any errors? Does this have something to do with the timing? It doesn't make sense to me why it works when I'm online and schedule it to run within a couple of minutes, but when I leave it be overnight it does not work.

Is it possible that the query is fine, but Looker only refreshes the data later in the day than 06.30 EST? Looker Studio has a refresh timer for data sources, which can be set to a specific time, and that time may be, say 12:00 EST. So the underlying data is refreshed and fine, but Looker doesn't reference the latest data until later in the day. Check the data sources in Looker Studio and the time the refresh is set to run at.

The underlying data  within BigQuery has not been updated for the aggregate table, so even  though it says the scheduled query ran without errors, for some reason the data is still missing from the table and Looker Studio has no new data to update with. Looker's data freshness is set to every 12 hours and I also manually refresh the data when I go to use the dashboard and still no changes.

A solution has been found: I set the scheduled query to run at a later time (later in the afternoon) after looking at the various times my source tables were being updated in BigQuery. This is now working successfully!
